# Create Index in Hive Sql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am facing error while try to create index in HiveSql database. Could you please help me on this.

My Query:

```
CREATE INDEX cp_index_user_id ON TABLE customerprofiles_2018(user_id);
```

Error:

> java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:133 cannot recognize input near '' '' ''

Comment: which version of hive are you using? Indexing has been removed from hive since version 3

Comment: I am using Hive 2.0 @eshirvana

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not assigning any name to index handler class :

```
CREATE INDEX cp_index_user_id ON TABLE customerprofiles_2018(user_id) AS 'index.handler.class.name';
```